# How to change this formula so it skips rows Excel

Tags: excel

I have this formula that I would like to change so it skips rows e.g. it looks at 1st row then 3rd 5th and so on. `{=AVERAGE(IF(MOD(COLUMN(Podatki!H7:T7);2)=0;Podatki!H7:T7;""))}`

I have come up with this so far but it doesn't seem to work.`{=AVERAGE(IF(MOD(COLUMN(OFFSET(Podatki!H7:T7;(ROW(Podatki!H7:T7)-6);0));2)=0;Podatki!H7:T7;""))}`

Any sugestions?

Comment: I assume you mean, skip *columns* and not skip *rows*?? So you want to find the average value of every other cell in the range `H7:T7`?

Comment: It already does that i want to use the same formula many times over but it has to skip 1 row every time I reuse it. So when I reuse the formula lets say the first time it does the 7th row then the 9th then 11th and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your formula already works as is but you want it to just skip all the even rows when you drag it down, you can do this:

```
= IF(MOD(ROW(),2)=0,"",<your working formula here>)
```

This formula effectively just "skips" all even rows when you drag the formula down.

I assume in your case the formula would be this:

```
= IF(MOD(ROW(),2)=0,"",AVERAGE(IF(MOD(COLUMN(Podatki!H7:T7);2)=0;Podatki!H7:T7;"")))
```

---

**EDIT**

Based on your recent comment, I think `INDIRECT` is what you are looking for.

Just replace all instances of your cell range in your formula,

```
Podatki!H7:T7
```

with this:

```
INDIRECT("Podatki!H"&(2*ROW()+5)&":T"&(2*ROW()+5))
```

You may want to adjust the `+5` part to whatever you need for your sheet. As is, for row 1, `(2*ROW()+5)` would return 7, for row 2, it would return 9, etc.

Comment: It seems people misunderstood me, when I sad it needed to skip rows I meant on the data sheet not on the sheet where I have the averages. Like in row 1 the formula would be {=AVERAGE(IF(MOD(COLUMN(Podatki!H7:T7);2)=0;Podatki!H7:T7;""))} in the second row it would be {=AVERAGE(IF(MOD(COLUMN(Podatki!H9:T9);2)=0;Podatki!H9:T9;""))} but if you have a lot of rows doing this by hand is tedious. Also please excuse my editing.

Comment: Thank you very much